# How can I select different databases for a model based on request parameters in Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have an application that I am considering porting to Sails.JS.

One of the big issues I am having is supporting the per-request database selection that we have right now.

Our app creates/uses a different database for each customer that we have and we select the database based on the request.

How could I achieve that in Sails.JS?

Could I write a Express middleware that would do this on a per request basis?