# Can I change databases on each request (Sails.js)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I have a few PHP scripts which I am in the process of migrating to Node.js. I am using Sails.js for this and I would like to know how I can change databases for each request based on a request parameter.

Currently I have 3-4 identical PostgreSQL databases. Let's just say that each database corresponds to a different client.

Below is a segment of the current PHP script where the database connection is established:

```
$database = $_GET['db'];
$conn_details = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=$database user=****** password=******";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_details);
```

Here you can see that the database name is coming from the request parameter "db".

I would like to have a similar functionality in my sails.js controller. I know that i can declare multiple databases in the connections.js and that I can have models use different databases but what i am after is for the models to stay the same and only the database to change based on each request.

I have found 2 similar questions but they have both stayed unanswered for quite some time now. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930432/how-can-i-select-different-databases-for-a-model-based-on-request-parameters-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797745/how-to-change-specify-database-used-during-runtime-with-sails-js))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like sub apps

[sails-hook-subapps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-subapps)

but it's experimental module. So i wouldn't recommend using it on production. Other option also not good is multiplying your Models like that:

- One main model with all methods, attributes and "stuff"
- Many models with connections config

In 'parent' model you will select to which model you want to send send action. For example write method:

```
getModel: function(dbName){
     return models[dbName];
}
```

in models Object you will store all Models with different connections. Not sure how validators will works in this scenario. You need to test if it will not be required do do something like this in child Models

```
attributes: parentModel.attributes
```